# Stop redirecting subdomain to main domain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

How can I stop my subdomain from redirecting to my main domain,

here's my code so that http://mydomain.com always add the www

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} .
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.mysite\.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.mysite.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

I've created a sub domain (sub.mysite.com) that is in a sub sub folder of my main site, and when I type sub.mysite.com it redirects to www.mysite.com/sub/sub/

thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify your sub folder which is related to your subdomain.
Edit your code to:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain\.domain\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.com/sub/sub/$1 [R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add an exclusion for that subdomain (like you've done with `www`):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} .
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.mysite\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^subdomain\.mysite\.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.mysite.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: @Prix It's to ensure the rule isn't applied to "short" GET requests, where the "Host" header is blank.

Comment: How can I do this while forcing an https?